# Validation of attributes from different models on one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, `User` and `Account`

- `Accounts` model validates presence of name and organization
- `User` model validates presence of email and password

I have one form for account creation which combines the two models: accountname and organization from `Account`, email and password from `User`.

How do I validate both models while creating an account?

Comment: Post some code so that answers can be more specific to your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely validate both models, the below should get you started but lookup any commands you don't recognise to get further help.

First link your models and allow nested attributes with validations for the child:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account
  validates_associated :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now use a `fields_for` helper to define your form:

```
<% form_for @user do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :email %>
  <% form.fields_for :account do |account_fields| %>
    <%= account_fields.input :organization %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Now in your controller when you update the attributes of @user the account attributes will automatically be updated with the account params. Then when the parent is validated, so will the children be.